# Transposing tables in a pivot to get count of values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My input is this

```
OCT NOV DEC
P1  P1  P1
P1  P1  P2
P1  P1  P3
P2  P1  P3
P3  P2  P3
P4  P2  P3
```

The P1 and P2 can change.

I want to set up a pivot so I can see the count of each project. Is this possible?

My desired output is

```
    OCT NOV DEC
P1  3   4   1
P2  1   2   1
P3  1   0   4
P4  1   0   0
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use a Pivot table? I think you could use `CountIfs()`?  What have you tried?

Comment: ah no there is no need for a pivot. I was just thinking that would be one possible solution. I'll check CountIfs(). Thanks